# Does Arduino Nano 33 BLE can advertise with custom payload?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to add custom payload in the BLE advertising packet and receive it from Android Service.
(Arduino --- {data} ---> Android)
However, ArduinoBLE library seems does not support a custom payload. (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLE)

So, How can I send data through the advertising sequence? (Not connect directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional advertising data is how BLE beacons work. iBeacons use ManufacturerData and Eddystone beacons use ServiceData. Looking through the documentation you linked to, I could not find an entry for ServiceData, but I did find one for ManufacturerData:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLEBLEsetManufacturerData

It is not clear from the Arduino documentation how you enter the [company identified](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/). Assuming you do not have a [company identifier](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/) then I think you could get away with using company ID 0xFFFF as long as your documentation and/or code comments make it clear it is not to be used in shipping products and is only for "internal testing" as it mentions at the bottom of the Bluetooth company identifier page.